# Unable to install .net framework 4.5 on Windows server 2008

Tags: installation, windows-server-2008, .net-framework-version

I have Windows Server 2008 with Service Pack 2. In that .Net framework 3.5 already exist.
Now I am trying to install .Net framework 4.5 but I got some error and it did not installed properly.

[image]

Server has

Microsoft .Net Framework 4 Client Profile

Microsoft .Net Framework 4 Extended

can these framework cause installation problem as well?

Someone please let me know what could be the problem and how to solve this.

Comment: Download and install https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Comment: downloaded from same place